# Google Analytics GAPI + PHP

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get all the analytics data from my-account.

screenshot:

[image]

What kind of dimensions or metrics do i need to pass?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimension will be **ga:country**

Metrics:

- ga:visits
- ga:visits
- ga:percentNewVisits
- ga:newVisits
- ga:visitBounceRate
- ga:pageviewsPerVisit
- ga:avgTimeOnSite
- ????
- ga:goal1Completions
- ga:goal1Value

???? - this may need to be computed from ga:goal1Starts/ga:goal1Completions

See list of all metrics [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

Hint: Use the [Core Reporting API Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).  You should be able to exactly replicate the numbers on Google Analytics interface.